# Migrating from Smart GWT Power 3.0 to 3.1

Tags: xml, gwt, maven-3, smartgwt, smartgwt-pro

I'm starting my intership next Monday. My mission is migrating an application from Smart gwt 3.0 to 3.1.

The application works with XML's Datasources and Xpath to query all data. It works within a Maven Project and uses Spring/Hibernate/Bitronix-JTA. According to my boss, when we upgrade smartgwt to 3.1 there is no error or exception thrown, however, most datasources don't work anymore. He said that the XPath is not valid anymore and it's being interpreted as String or something like that.

Monday I'll see what the issue looks like, but before that I'd rather preferred to ask question here to have your opinions. If someone has already seen this issue he can make my ideas clear and help to make a good beginning. If I've got the source code like POM or *.ds.xml or output exception I'll post it here as I get them.

Answer (score 0):

First thanks to Caleb who corrected my previous question.
I compared the two applications that run separately on version 3.0 and 3.1, and I discovered an issue fot the moment.
Some GridLists are not being filled correctly ,I'm sure the query (SQL or XQuery or XPath I dont know yet) run properly, because in the header I have the number of records returned by executeFetch () (104 in the photos), however GridList is empty, I'd rather say the records are empty,as you can see, the Checkbox are there... I think problem comes from the instanciation of the records, I haven't finished yet analyzing the code Source as it is a bit large (even HUGE) and it is not mine, I first have to get used my predecessor's way of programming, here two pictures that illustrates the problem, I'm always searching by my side but any kind of trick, hint or experience is welcome
Thank you all.

[Smart GWT 3.0](http://img15.hostingpics.net/pics/731790Version30.png)
[Smart GWT 3.1](http://img15.hostingpics.net/pics/161975Version31.png)

Answer (score 0):

First of all i recommend you to check the release notes of SmartGWT 3.1. You will get an overview of what changed and with what type of functionalities you should most care about.

Despite of some problems you may have with the DataSource functionality, you might find some changes in the page layout behavior. I had planned a migration from the 3.0 to the 3.1 in January but it never passed the tests. All went fine, except one thing: The application needs to show some documents in various formats and PDF is obviously one of them. The problem is that i need to render it with some SmartGWT Windows open in front of the rendered document. In Chrome and IE this was not a problem in v3.0 but in v3.1 the windows never stay in front of it. Always shows up behind the plugin loaded by the browser to show the document.

Good Luck!